# Why was my question closed as "opinion-based"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I recently asked a [question asking for verification of a claim I found in an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388971/why-would-i-choose-a-private-read-only-auto-property-over-a-read-only-field). In the comments section, there was some disagreement about whether my understanding of the article was accurate in the first place, but that is beside the point here.

I was asking for a tangible, factual advantage of using one code construct over another.

What I am confused about is why my question was closed as **opinion-based**.

Surely, it is possible to have an opinion that deviates from, or even contradicts verifiable facts from specifications etc. But I'd argue that alone cannot be a sufficient criterion for considering a question "opinion-based", as that would render absolutely all questions opinion-based.

Likewise, I was *not* asking about what the author of the article I quoted thought. That would ... well, frankly, even that would not possibly be "opinion-based", although just a single person on Earth *could* answer the question (the author of the article).

I suspect these VTC were largely based on a very narrow interpretation of the quoted text (or, let's say, some kind of word-by-word parsing). Even so, I disagree with the close reason: While my premise may be disputed, the *question itself* does not hinge on that premise. Maybe I should just have skipped the context and just asked right away:

> Is there any *general* tangible benefit of using a private read-only property over a private read-only field that applies in all circumstances?

That is an absolutely answerable question, and I'd understand if it were maybe closed for a lack of research effort (my actual question does contain some reasoning for why properties are preferrable to fields *in certain cases*), but it is obviously not opinion-based.

Therefore - the way my question was closed as *opinion-based*, it feels to me like some users just wanted to "shoot down" the question out of mere disagreement with the premise, rather than for the question itself.

Comment: After re-reading the question a couple of times, it is still not clear to me what you are actually asking. Paraphrased, there seems to be "why use A instead of B", "why use A at all", and "why *always* use A instead of B"; phrasing two of these as "why would *I*" is just the cherry on top. Frankly, I could see all of "needs details", "needs focus" and "opinion based" apply. It certainly does not just need disagreement with your premise to VTC.

Answer (score 5):

The post you linked to certainly *looks* (not necessarily *is*) like you are asking peers to exercise at reading the mind of an article author, so this is most likely the reason it got closed (which is substantiated by the [ensuing discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388971/why-would-i-choose-a-private-read-only-auto-property-over-a-read-only-field#comment117368939_66388971) on what author actually wanted to say).

Admittedly, I think the question falls in line with the "focus on a more fact-based line of questioning" reasoning [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) provides for allowing opinion-ish questions to stay open.

Your post may stand a better chance of reopening if you shift focus from the "why would I" part which incites others to speculate about the article to something like "what are the upsides/downsides" (or pros and cons), as well as remove the last paragraph of this meta post, which some might be seen as a rant (and that surely does not help your case).